# Creating a real loading screen between levels in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: c++, unreal-4, loading, blueprints

I'm trying to create a loading screen to pop up between levels in Unreal Engine 4. I want to have a traditional loading screen such as the loading screen in Skyrim, where the player presses play and text alongside a small model pops up until the game is finished loading.

However, the only information I have found on the internet is related to level streaming which is definitely not what I want. The game I'm working on has very big levels with different gamemodes in each of them, which level streaming can't handle. Also I've found some obsolete plugins to do this which no longer works on the latest UE versions. I've also found some "hacks" that are pretty much display an icon on the main menu while waiting for the "Open Level" blueprint function ends up loading the level, yet I'm skeptical if this technique will work when the level to load is quite big and complex.

How can I create this loading screen? where I can find information on the topic?

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to look at MoviePlayer API, 
You can use a MoviePlayer, despite the name it can also draw widgets, UMG/Slate widgets.

It requires some little C++ knowledge to achieve it. 
You have a tutorial here: 
https://forums.unrealengine.com/community/community-content-tools-and-tutorials/67244-seamless-proper-loading-screens-play-movies-audio-animated-widgets

Comment: the link is broken.
this one seems to be very similar to what you point at https://unrealcommunity.wiki/loading-screen-243mzpq1